# How to solve this error ---> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nbul":"^5.1.0","babel'

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a React project, but it is showing some kind of error. This is the error

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nbul":"^5.1.0","babel'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Anyone help me to solve this error

Comment: Don't know how you create your project,Via create-react-app?Can you show your package.json?

Comment: Hi @MinimalistYing I created project by typing npx create-react-app crazy

Comment: try `npm cache clean --force`